# How to remove space after comma in list in python

Tags: python, arrays, append

```
class Solution:
    def buildArray(self, nums):
    
        ans=[]
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            ans.append(nums[nums[i]])
        return ans

    
sol = Solution()  
res = sol.buildArray([0,2,1,5,3,4])
print(res)
```

output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3]
```

The problem is in the output , iam sturggling to remove space after comma  ',' in the list . Can any body help me with this one

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: The output looks perfect. If you try to print any list, the list representation will look exactly like this. It's also clean and clear.

Comment: Iam solving a problem in the leetcode , when i implement this code , its giving me the wrong answer as it has a space after comma .

Comment: So... exactly what I thought. It's not wrong, you just don't understand that it's correct. `[0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3]` and `[0,1,2,4,5,3]` are exactly the same list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn the list into a string first, which will make that kind of manipulation easier.

Try replacing your last line for this:

```py
res_str = str(res).replace(", ", ',')
print(res_str)
```

Comment: Thank you it solved my problem ❣❣❣

Comment: @LakshmiNarasimha What problem? Likely your actual problem is that you don't understand that you don't have a problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific format you want from your list, then I would just create that format instead of trying to modify the list's internal string result.

```py
arr = [0, 1, 2]
res = '[{}]'.format(','.join(map(str, arr)))
print(res)
```

Should result in: `[0,1,2]`

EDIT: Fixed a mistake that shouldn't have been.

Comment: To make it work, swap `','.join(arr)` for `','.join(map(str, arr))` as join expects to recieve an iterable of strings